# Best practice to handle global 500 errors in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a django app running with MySQL and Redis as backend

I have a function called `redis_helper()` to do redis queries.

But sometimes Redis crash and needs sometime to bootup, so I need to return a friendly HTTP 500 error message.

The problem is, django only defines `Http404(Exception)` class in `django/http/__init__.py`, not `Http500()`, so I have to manually add `try ... except` in every view function where `redis_helper()` was involved. It feel a bit ugly and repeating work.

Are there any convenient way to raise server 500 error *not* using `return HttpResponseServerError()` in view functions? If I have to write `Http500` class myself which file is the best place to write it?

Regards and thank you!

Comment: There is no particular Http500 exception. Basically you don't want to do something like this, since this might hide your original error. Stay with your try-except block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, now I understand how `Http404` works. So you have to define this `Http500` exception somewhere, and catch it in middleware.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have no `try:` block around the `Redis` call.

Is that the case?

If so, the answer is use `try:` block.

> so I have to manually add try ... except in every view function where redis_helper() was involved.

Correct.

> It feel a bit ugly and repeating work.

Incorrect.  Every view function must return an `HttpResponse` object.  You have to actually write that code.

I'm sorry if writing view functions seems repeating, but, that's they way they must work.  They must return an `HttpResponse` object.

---

Edit.  Also.  Please **read** this:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view

Comment: ok, I have `try` block, but what should I `raise` if something is wrong?

Comment: @est: `raise`?  Why would you raise anything?  You can return an HttpResponse with an error message.  Why are you trying to `raise` something?

Comment: @S.Lott By "return an HttpResponse" did you mean I have to modify every function in views.py which called `edis_helper()` ? I think the point of inventing `raise Http500` is to avoid this.

Comment: @est: "modify every function in views.py which called edis_helper()".  Yes.  That's one solution that **always** works.  It can't be that many.  If it is, you've really done a poor job of design.

Comment: @S.Lott Why calling `redis_helper()` multiple times is bad design? Let me ask you this, how would you write a *specific*, unified error page if django's `auth.users` model went wrong?

Comment: @est: Hold up a second.  I said: "I'm sorry if writing view functions seems repeating, but, that's they way they must work. They must return an HttpResponse object."  I would simply return the proper HttpResponse object.  That's all.  "It can't be that many. If it is, you've really done a poor job of design."  If you have so many view functions that you cannot change all of them, your web site is too complex, too large and badly designed.  Exactly how many `redis_helper()` function calls do you have?  6? 12? 24?  just fix them to return pages properly.  Over 100?  You have a bad design.